# Display list based on condition in Yii

Tags: phpmyadmin, yii, yii-components

I am trying to hide a list item in `Yii CList` view based on a visibility condition.

Based on an `id` that I get from the list , I need to check whether a condition exists and display that item  only if that condition is true.

I have a `request_tbl` and `ibnvite_tbl`. Request table contains all requests in the system. It contains a field named `invite_type`. **If** invite_type is 3 , there will be an insertion in invite table with comma separated values of invited users with corresponding `request_id`.

**My requirement is:**

On a user login, based on my list view, `if invite_type is 3 need to display the list items from request table for the logged in user_id`. if the invite_type not equal to 3 we can list the items without checking,

For me only white space is showing in case there is no user_id in invite table when the invite_type is 3. **How can I display the items?**.

**If more details are required , I will add it.**

Comment: Could you improve formatting (emphasise problem, add a bit space), and perhaps add some code?

Comment: If I understood your issue correctly, here' how I will solve it (although there may be better ways to do it). I will check for the invite_type value with a queryScalar in the controller action and based on the value will render the appropriate List in the view. It results in one extra query though.